# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

url: http://www.gws-mbca.org

The slide show works in Firefox. It used to work in IE and Chrome. Now I get the following error in both IE and Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined

The script is linked using a `<script type="...>` in the document head.

The code in the web page is as follows:

```
<section style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
  <img src="./rPix/rp1.jpg" id="slide" width="900" height="200" alt="slide show images" />
</section>


<body onload="runShow();">
```

The function `runShow` is part of slideshow.js - Code is as follows:

```
/* An automatically rotating slide show using Javascript and the DOM.
   This script cobbled together by Paul D.J. Vandenberg */

var j = 1;
var pix = new Array(11);

for (i = 0; i < pix.length; i++) {
  pix[i] = "rPix/rp"+j+".jpg";
  j++;
}

var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
var limit = pix.length - 1;

function runShow() { 
  if (index > limit) {
    index = 0;
  }
  document.slide.src = pix[index];
  setTimeout("runShow()", 10000);
  index++;
}
```

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("slide")` instead of `document.slide`. Also make sure that the `section` elements is *inside* the body, not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `runShow()` *after* the `id="slide"` element has been added to the DOM.

`document.slide` is shorthand for `document.getElementById("slide")`. The latter will return `null` when no element with that id is defined.

Comment: So the DOM doesn't include the definition "slide" until after it's declared as an "id=" attribute of an <img> tag in the body of the page. But since it worked in Firefox that sort of implies that Firefox builds the DOM before the <body onload> executes. It's quirks like this that can drive one mad.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM must be loaded before the document can access any elements. Usually an [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload) event is used when the script is in the `<head>`

```
window.onload = function(){
 var j = 1;
 var pix = new Array(11);

 for (i = 0; i < pix.length; i++) {
  pix[i] = "rPix/rp"+j+".jpg";
  j++;
 }

 var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;
 var limit = pix.length - 1;

 window.runShow = function() { 
  if (index > limit) {
   index = 0;
  }
  document.slide.src = pix[index];
  setTimeout("runShow()", 10000);
  index++;
 }
};
```

"The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading." -MDN

---

*Suggested improvements*

I thought I would throw this part in because there are few things I think you can improve here as far as your approach and decided to offer some suggestions.

1. Lets remove `body onload="runShow()"` from your code and make it just `<body>` or whatever other class etc you might have on there.
2. Lets also go in and use an interval instead of a timeout because for longrunning processes they are more accurate.
3. Also, lets try to remove all strings from the callbacks.

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
window.onload = function(){
 var pix = [];//array to hold image source strings
 var limit = 10;//0 based count for images
 for( var i = 0; i < limit+1; i++ ){//runs 11 times
  pix.push("rPix/rp"+(i+1)+".jpg";//push incrementally adds to pix array
 }
 var index = limit;//last index for image source in pix array
 var slide = document.getElementById("slide");//cache slide image element
 function runShow(){
  if( index > limit ) index = 0;//cycle images by array length
  slide.src = pix[index++];//change slide image using cached element
 }
 runShow();//run on load
 setInterval(runShow,10000);//run every 10 seconds
};
</head>
<body>
 <section style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
  <img src="./rPix/rp1.jpg" id="slide" width="900" height="200" alt="slide show images" />
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Encapsulating everything within the winbdow.onload function fixed the original error. Now all three browsers throw an "Uncaught ReferenceError: runShow is not defined". I'm a little surprised that putting runShow within the context of the window.onload function would make it invisible to the web page function call. Looks like time to do a little more digging.

Comment: @Paul - Sorry about that, I see what happened. When wrapped in the load event, `runShow` becomes local to that function. There is actually a lot going on here. Calling the function from timeout with a string isn't exactly best practice, neither is using inline javascript on the body tag (or making runShow global as I am suggesting). But the quickest way to fix this problem will be to make the `runShow` function global. We can do that by attaching it to the global scope (`window`). Please see my edit, and note the `window.runShow = function()` change. This should accommodate your situation.

Comment: Thanks to Travis J, Felix Kling, and Frits van Campen. Code is working now (see below). Had some indexing errors - probably not doing something right, but a blend of Travis J's example and my original code fixed that.

Comment: I was getting an "undefined" error with runShow as shown in the example. Unless my hand execution is wrong the conditional test (index > limit) allows indexing beyond the last element in the array. Changing the conditional to (index >= limit) fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
So here's what the code looks like now.

/* An automatically rotating slide show using Javascript and the DOM.
   This script cobbled together by Paul D.J. Vandenberg with a nice 
   assist from stackoverflow */

window.onload = function() {

  var j = 1;
  var pix = new Array(11);

  for (i = 0; i < pix.length; i++) {
    pix[i] = "rPix/rp"+j+".jpg";
    j++;
  }

  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1;    // Start at a random slide
  var limit = pix.length - 1;
  var slide = document.getElementById("slide"); // Cache slide image element

  function runShow() { 
    if (index > limit) {
      index = 0;
    }
    slide.src = pix[index++];
  }
  setInterval(runShow, 10000);  // Interval more reliable than timeOut
  runShow();
}
```